# How to program chess bishop movement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a chess game and I need do movement bishop but I can't. We choose the figures positions and it should work in case of any layout. Here is my code.

This is JS code. Here I create board, give each box id and add white bishop which position choose I by prompt. Now I can't continue. I must find the step of the bishop it's so hard, I try different ways but it didn't work.

Here is how I code my board. Bishops can move only diagonally. Additionally here is html code, I give some styles for board numbers and letters.

```js
var ChessArray = ["k" , "A8", "A7", "A6", "A5" , "A4" , "A3" , "A2" , "A1",
"B8", "B7", "B6", "B5" , "B4" , "B3" , "B2" , "B1",
"C8", "C7", "C6", "C5" , "C4" , "C3" , "C2" , "C1",
"D8", "D7", "D6", "D5" , "D4" , "D3" , "D2" , "D1", 
"E8", "E7", "E6", "E5" , "E4" , "E3" , "E2" , "E1" ,
"F8", "F7", "F6", "F5" , "F4" , "F3" , "F2" , "F1",
"G8", "G7", "G6", "G5" , "G4" , "G3" , "G2" , "G1",
"H8", "H7", "H6", "H5" , "H4" , "H3" , "H2" , "H1"]


// create board
var board = document.getElementById("mainChessBoard");

    for (var i=0; i< ChessArray.length-1; i++){
    
    board.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).style.backgroundColor = parseInt((i / 8) + i) % 2 == 0 ? '#ababab' : 'white';
    
    }
    
    
    // give id
    for (var i=0; i<8; i++){ 
    board.children[i].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+1]);
    board.children[i+8].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+2]);
    board.children[i+16].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+3]);
    board.children[i+24].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+4]);
    board.children[i+32].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+5]);
    board.children[i+40].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+6]);
    board.children[i+48].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+7]);
    board.children[i+56].setAttribute("id" , ChessArray[8*i+8]);
    }

    // // bishop
    var white_bishop = prompt("please enter position of white bishop",); 
    
    function Function_for_bishop() {
    var t=0;
    for ( i=0; i< ChessArray.length; i++){
       
            if ( ChessArray[i]  == white_bishop  ){
               
                t += 1;
            
          }
      
    }
    if ((t == 0)){
            prompt("FALSE",);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(white_bishop).innerHTML = "&#9815" ;
        document.getElementById(white_bishop).style.fontSize = "80px";
        alert("Bishop") 
    }
    } 
    
     Function_for_bishop()
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta Charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
         #mainChessBoard{
        
               width:640px;
               height:640px;
               border:1px solid black;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            }
    
         div{
             width:80px;
             height:80px;
             float:left;
            }
       
         .letter{
          width:660px;
          display: block;
          margin-bottom: 10px
         
         }
         #number{
          font-size: 37px;
             position: relative;
             left: 655px;
             bottom: 747px
            }   
     .letter>p{
       display: inline;
       font-size: 80px;
      margin-right: 24px
      } 
     .last {
      margin-right: 0 
      }  

     .numbers {
      height: 640px;
      width: 640px;  
      } 
     .numbers p {
      display: block
      } 
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>    
 <div id="mainChessBoard"> 
 </div>   
  <div class = "letter">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
  <p>G</p>
  <p class="last">H</p>
 </div> 
 <div id="number">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
 </div>
  </div> 
 <script src="script.js"> </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving diagonally will entail moving the same number of squares both horizontally and vertically. In a 2D array, you'd just need to check that `abs(old[x] - current[x]) === abs(old[y] - current[y])`. In a 1D array like you've got, you'll need to compute the row (`Math.trunc(position / 8)`) for the y position and the column (`position % 8`) and do the same calculation - making sure the number of rows traversed and the number of columns traversed are the same.